# Grouped by category (teen, adult, senior) and alphabetized by last name

Tags: mysql

Example:
On using SQL command:

```
select last_name,first_name from person group by category order by last_name;
```

I'm getting only three values. I should get all lastname, first name of teens,adults,senior in seperate rows:

[image: Sample Table]

[image: Output]

I should get
Example:

```
lastname   category
A             a
B             a
C             b
D             B
```

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks Juan from next time time on-wards i will implement this method

Comment: No. From this time. Now.

Comment: Or you could edit this one to a better format, because as right now doesnt offer enough information to give you an answer

Comment: `GROUP BY category` indicates that you want one row from each category.  Why do you expect more than that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your structure is wrong.

`GROUP BY` is used in aggregate functions such as `count()`, `max()`, or `sum()`. You'll want to use multiple `ORDER BY` statements. They apply in order.

```
SELECT
    last_name,
    first_name
FROM person 
ORDER BY 
    category, 
    last_name;
```